# Delete the autogenerated row in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid. It is bound to the collection of Person called People.

User is allowed to add new rows, i mean `CanUserAddRows = true`.

<kbd>Enter</kbd> key in my DataGrid works as <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.

My DataGrid has three columns in it namely : FirstName, LastName, City.
FirstName is Reqired. And the other two are not Compulsory.

When user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the First Cell of last row (Automatically Generated Row) and if that cell is empty then computer guesses that user don't want to add more data to the DataGrid and the focus moves to a button outside the DataGrid.

All is working well upto this point.

**Problems:**

By pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> on last row's first cell and keeping it empty, the button outside the DataGrid gets focused. At that time I don't want the user to see the last empty row in DataGrid.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried two events: 1. GotFocus and 2. LostFocus

In GotFocus event of DataGrid I set `CanUserAddRows = true` 
and In LostFocus event of DataGrid I set `CanUserAddRows = false`

But Unfortunately that didn't work as when textBlock inside DataGrid's cell get's focus, the DataGrid thinks that it has lost its focus. So, CanUserAddRows is set to false and I get error.

**My Code:**

person.cs

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            return _people;
        }
        set
        {
            _people = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("People");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="93*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="14*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="maindg" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Margin="0,0,0.4,-0.2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                  PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_KeyDown_1" SelectedIndex="0" GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" 
                  SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" >
        </DataGrid>

        <Button Height="20" Width="50" Content="Save" Margin="2.8,9.8,10.4,11.8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSave" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int FindRowIndex(DataGridRow row)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid =
            ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(row)
            as DataGrid;

        int index = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.
            IndexFromContainer(row);

        return index;
    }

    private object ExtractBoundValue(DataGridRow row,
                             DataGridCell cell)
    {
        // find the column that this cell belongs to
        DataGridBoundColumn col =
           cell.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;

        // find the property that this column is bound to
        Binding binding = col.Binding as Binding;
        string boundPropertyName = binding.Path.Path;

        // find the object that is related to this row
        object data = row.Item;

        // extract the property value
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(data);

        PropertyDescriptor property = properties[boundPropertyName];
        if (property != null)
        {
            object value = property.GetValue(data);

            return value;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void DataGrid_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Enter) return;

        DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
        //here we just find the cell got focused ...
        //then we can use the cell key down or key up
        // iteratively traverse the visual tree
        while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridCell) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        if (dep == null)
            return;

        if (dep is DataGridCell)
        {
            try
            {
                //cancel if datagrid in edit mode
                maindg.CommitEdit();


                //Check if selected cell is on first column and last row
                if (maindg.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex == 0)
                {
                    DependencyObject dep1 = dep;
                    while ((dep1 != null) && !(dep1 is DataGridRow))
                    {
                        dep1 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep1);
                    }

                    DataGridRow row = dep1 as DataGridRow;

                    if (FindRowIndex(row) == maindg.Items.Count - 1)
                    {
                        if (ExtractBoundValue(row, dep as DataGridCell) == null)
                        {
                            btnSave.Focus();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                maindg.CancelEdit();
            }
            //get current cell
            DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;
            //deselect current cell
            cell.IsSelected = false;
            //find next right cell
            var nextCell = cell.PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Right);
            //if next right cell null go for find next ro first cell
            if (nextCell == null)
            {
                DependencyObject nextRowCell;
                nextRowCell = cell.PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Down);
                //if next row is null so we have no more row Return;
                if (nextRowCell == null)
                {
                    nextRowCell = dep;
                    while ((nextRowCell as DataGridCell).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Left) != null)
                        nextRowCell = (nextRowCell as DataGridCell).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Left);
                    //change current cell
                    maindg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(nextRowCell as DataGridCell);
                    //change selected cell
                    (nextRowCell as DataGridCell).IsSelected = true;
                    return;
                }
                //we do this because we cant use FocusNavigationDirection.Next for function PredictFocus
                //so we have to find it this way
                while ((nextRowCell as DataGridCell).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Left) != null)
                    nextRowCell = (nextRowCell as DataGridCell).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Left);
                //set new cell as next cell
                nextCell = nextRowCell;
            }

            //change current cell
            maindg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(nextCell as DataGridCell);
            //change selected cell
            (nextCell as DataGridCell).IsSelected = true;
            // start edit mode
            maindg.BeginEdit();
        }
        //handl the default action of keydown
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for putting all relevant code here in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. On **`GotFocus()`** simply set **`CanUserAddRows`** to **`True`**. And on **`LostFocus()`** handler set it to **`False`**.

Since LostFocus handler gets called when focus moves within the grid also, you can check for property **`IsKeyboardFocusWithin`** to know if focus is within grid or not.

```
private void maindg_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!maindg.CanUserAddRows)
    {
        maindg.CanUserAddRows = true;
    }
}

private void maindg_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!maindg.IsKeyboardFocusWithin && maindg.CanUserAddRows)
    {
        maindg.CanUserAddRows = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just tried the code that you posted in your answer. At the first look it looks like it works perfectly. But another problem comes in. When I press enter on the first cell of the last row and if that cell is empty, then focus moves to the button outside the DataGrid. So, I thought it works perfectly. Now new problem is that when press down arrow key on the button, the grid's first row's last cell gets focus. And then if I press Enter key, then the automatically generated row at the bottom disappears.

Comment: I tried in the sample you provided. And indeed last cell of first row get's focus and when I press enter focus moves to the first cell of the empty row. However, I was able to produce with Tab key press on button moved focus to first cell of first row and on press enter, empty row gets hide.

Comment: And the problem goes away with safety checks in place on `GetFocus` and `LostFocus` of inverting the property only when value is vice-versa and it works. May be setting it everytime when dataGrid got focus produce some undesired behaviour. Try with updated methods and see if problem still persists.

Comment: Yes, your updated code works well. Thank you very much. But there also I get a small problem. When you fill data in 3 rows and leave the first cell of fourth row empty and press enter, focus moves to button. Now press down arrow key and then press enters as many times when you reach the fourth row's first cell. Now keep it empty again and press enter key. It will allow you to go to second cell instead of focusing the button.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce issue you mentioned at my end. It's moving to button. Anyhow I just posted the code when focus moved out of the dataGrid. Focus movement logic is within your posted code (might be some flaw in it). Check by placing breakpoints in your code that what causes it to moved to second row.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and let you know.